# Hide hash from URL when page jump

Tags: javascript, html, anchor, href

I have a link on my menu that targets to an anchor on another page.

```
<a href="http://www.mylink.com.br/mylink/#anchor">
```

And I want to hide the `#anchor` from URL.

---

I've tried another solution, look:

```
$('#menu #mylink2').click(function() {
   document.location.href = "www.mysite.com/mysite/";
});
```

and then, I need to activate a script to scroll to the div after the page loads:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $("#divtoscroll").offset().top }, 2500);
});
```

but I don't know how to attach that event to the previous. The way it is, everytime the page loads, it scrolls to the div.

Any help?

---

I did it!
I added "contato" on the final of the URL to differentiate it from the other links.

```
$('#menu #mylink2').click(function() {
   document.location.href = "www.mysite.com/mysite/contato";
});
```

And used it to recognize the URL and activate the document ready function.

```
var url = "www.mysite.com/mysite/contato";
if (location.href==url) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $("#allcontentcontact").offset().top }, 2500);
    });
}
else {
}
```

Works perfectly! Thanks for the help.

Comment: I am 99% sure it is not possible

Comment: So it's impossible to target to an anchor on another page without adding the hash to the URL?

Comment: Do you have access to the server generating the pages?

Comment: I'm very close to what I want. Look again the post, please!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware it is not possible to do this, as it is what tells the browser which section of the page to jump to.

You may be able to do this using the amount of pixels and javascript, but it would not work for all cases.
*Example:*

```
 window.scrollBy(0, 500);
```

You could use jQuery to scroll to a specific element ID on a page, but this would require a trigger on that page, such as a click, or even page load. Example below uses click.

```
$("#button").click(function() {
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#elementtoScrollToID").offset().top
}, 2500);
```

});

Comment: So it's impossible to target to an anchor on another page without changing the URL?

Comment: I think there are jQuery plugins that allow you to "scroll to" an element (identified by a selector), which would be a bit more precise. See if you can find a couple to improve this answer :-)

Comment: `scrollBy` and `scrollTo` might work on the **current** page but not on **another** linked page.

Comment: I have an idea, look at the post again.